# Problem with sh profile in IPython on Mac

Tags: python, shell, profile

I recently heard about profiles in python and quickly discovered the sh profile. I went to invoke it to try it out and got the following error on my Mac running Snow Leopard and the system Python2.6. Anyone else see this before? I was thinking about trying to reinstall the IPython egg to see if it fixed it, but thought I'd ask if any other users had seen something similar (on an Apple computer most likely).

```
mwoods 5 22:11:48 ~$ ipython -p sh
[IPythonApp] Config file not found, skipping: <ipython_config_sh.py>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/ipython-0.11.bzr.r1205-py2.6.egg/IPython/core/application.py", line 223, in load_file_config
    self.file_config = loader.load_config()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/ipython-0.11.bzr.r1205-py2.6.egg/IPython/config/loader.py", line 227, in load_config
    self._find_file()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/ipython-0.11.bzr.r1205-py2.6.egg/IPython/config/loader.py", line 234, in _find_file
    self.full_filename = filefind(self.filename, self.path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/ipython-0.11.bzr.r1205-py2.6.egg/IPython/utils/genutils.py", line 569, in filefind
    (filename, path_dirs))
IOError: File does not exist in any of the search paths: 'ipython_config_sh.py', ('/Users/mwoods', u'/Users/mwoods/.ipython')
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Feb 11 2010, 00:51:29) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.11.bzr.r1205 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object'. ?object also works, ?? prints more.

In [1]:
```

Comment: I recall hearing that the version of Python running on Macs is a bit odd. You might want to look up some of the differences and see if they may effect what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had success running `ipython --profile=sh`. However, the features of the sh profile (as [advertised here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/shell.html)) weren't available.